# #region in .cshtml (Razor view)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, razor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regions In ASP.NET Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392931/regions-in-asp-net-views)

Is there a way of doing regions in Razor view (.cshtml)

```
   '#region'
   '#endregion'
```

Comment: Thanks i was unable to find the duplicate hence posted.